# Scrollable element with flexible top-edge and fixed left/right/bottom (no js)

Tags: html, css

I have a `<p>` and underneath a scrollable `<div>`. The text-element is usually a one-liner (left side in example-image), but sometimes it has multiple lines (right side in example-image).

[image]

What i want is, that the top-edge of my scrollable element orientates on the height of the `<p>` while the bottom-edge is fixed.

In my example i faked it by adding `position: absolute;` and `top: 120px;` for the scroll-box on the left and `top: 220px;` for the scroll-box on the right. But i never know how high the `<p>` will be.

In the end it needs to run on IE8 :( But it would help to have any working example in a newer browser to find a solution on that old crappy thing.

Here is a [CodePen for it](http://codepen.io/DerZyklop/pen/pGqou).

Here my HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor conseteoamet.</p>
    <div class="scroll">
      Lorem<br>ipsum<br>dolor<br>sit <br>amet<br>, consetetur<br> sadipscing<br> elitr,<br> sed <br>diam <br>nonumy <br>e <br>sit <br>amet, <br>consetetur s<br>adipscing <br>elitr, <br>sed <br>diam n<br>onumy e <br>sit <br>amet, <br>consetetur <br>sadipscing <br>elitr, <br>sed diam nonumy <br>esit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br>sed diam<br> nonumy <br>eirmod <br>tempoamet.<br>Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sit <br>amet, <br>consetetur <br>sadipscing el
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy e sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy e sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy e sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempoamet.</p>
    <div class="scroll">
      Lorem<br>ipsum<br>dolor<br>sit <br>amet<br>, consetetur<br> sadipscing<br> elitr,<br> sed <br>diam <br>nonumy <br>e <br>sit <br>amet, <br>consetetur s<br>adipscing <br>elitr, <br>sed <br>diam n<br>onumy e <br>sit <br>amet, <br>consetetur <br>sadipscing <br>elitr, <br>sed diam nonumy <br>esit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br>sed diam<br> nonumy <br>eirmod <br>tempoamet.<br>Lorem ipsum <br>dolor sit <br>amet, <br>consetetur <br>sadipscing el
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
*
  box-sizing: border-box

.outer
  width: 800px
  height: 500px
  position: relative
  border: 1px solid #999

.inner-1, .inner-2
  background: #ddd
  padding: 2em
  margin: 2em
  position: absolute
  overflow: scroll
  top: 0
  width: 45%
  bottom: 0

.inner-1
  left: 0
.inner-2
  right: 0

.scroll
  border: 2px solid #aaa
  background: #eee
  overflow: scroll
  position: absolute
  left: 0
  right: 0
  bottom: 0

.inner-1 .scroll
  top: 110px
.inner-2 .scroll
  top: 220px
```